# [UITableViewSectionElement release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, dealloc

I have spent a great deal of time trying to debug this error. When Zombie is enabled, this is printed on the console. I am very careful to not release things when I shouldn't. The main issues with debugging this is that:

- It happens seemingly randomly
- I don't know what a UITableViewSectionElement is and can't find any resources on the internet to tell me
- The stack traces in zombie or just running with zombie enabled don't include any part of my code

Does anyone know what UITableViewSectionElement's are? Has anyone seen this and may know how to fix it?

Replies are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560693/load-uitableview-crash-caused-by-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance